# Google Maps API3 - Filter (Multiple options for each marker)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi I have managed to get this working so the markers load and have multiple categories assigned to each.

The filter works by matching the values from the checkboxes and the marker, if this is not equal to, the marker's visibility is set to none.

The issue I have is the checkbox isn't taking into account the other checkboxes and I'm now stuck.

Any help of guidance is very appreciated!

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry please find here : https://jsfiddle.net/emux5evL/2/

Answer (score 1):

You will need to iterate all markers irrespective of which checkbox is checked or unchecked. You will need to use the code as given below. It checks the category of each marker and sets its visibility to false only if none of the categories applicable for that marker are unchecked.

```
/**
 * Function to filter markers by category
*/

$(".marker_filter").click(function() {

      for (i = 0; i < gmarkers1.length; i++) {
        marker = gmarkers1[i];
        var setVisible = false;
        for (j = 0; j < marker.category.length; j++) {
          setVisible = $("#" + marker.category[j]).is(":checked") || setVisible
        }

        marker.setVisible(setVisible);
      }
    });
```

You will need to set an id for the check boxes and make them checked by default in the HTML file.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="marker_filter" name="Option 1" value="option1" id="option1" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" class="marker_filter" name="Option 2" value="option2" id="option2" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" class="marker_filter" name="Option 3" value="option3" id="option3" checked/>
```

The updated code is available at https://jsfiddle.net/emux5evL/5/